# jQuery siblings does not select options inside div?

Tags: jquery

```js
$('.input-group select').change(function() {
    
    var value = $(this).val();
alert($('.input-group select').siblings('select').children('option').length); 
    $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group 1">
    <select name="select1">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group 2">
    <select name="select2">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have the following code and would like to select options inside select so when user select in first value A that this value is disabled in second select box and inverse.

I found siblings of jQuery but i im unable to select it in div...where i im doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: Post your code here in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of using jsfiddle. And don't try to get around the rule that a question that links to jsfiddle has to have code in it.

Comment: Sorry for that...i updated quesrtion with code snipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this...
An assumption made here is that there are only two `select` boxes in the HTML that this functionality should be designed for:

```js
$ = jQuery;
$("#select1, #select2").on("change", function() {
     if($(this).attr("id") == "select1"){
        src = "#select1"; target="#select2";
     }
     else{
        src = "#select2"; target="#select1";
     }

     $(target).children().removeAttr("disabled");
     $(target).find("option[value="+$(src).val()+"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group 1">
    <select id="select1">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group 2">
    <select id="select2">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**EDIT** 
Updated the jQuery to address the concern expressed in the comments section. An assumption made here is that the new `select` boxes will be added in a similar fashion to the existing ones, i.e. under a new `<div class="input-group">`. Therefore, according to the given HTML layout the updated jQuery would be:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).parent().siblings()
           .find("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

**Suggestions:**

- Wrap the above code inside a `function` and call that function whenever a new `select` box is added dynamically - again, it is assumed that it'll be added under `<div class="input-group">` and that there will be a parent `<div>` right above the first such element.
- Change `<option>No Match</option>` to `<option value="0">No Match</option>` or alike.

Comment: Thanks...this works as expected..but i have two select boxes when page loads...then user clicks on button add new select box so i need to do that with all select box that is added dynamically..could you please rewrite code to do this on all dynamically added select boxes? i im using when adding dynamic box id="select3" id="select4" etc

Comment: Using siblings i can get with multiple select boxes..but attached onchange event for siblings does not work in my example..so if someone could help...thanks

Comment: @John, please check the edits and the suggestions. Hopefully that should work. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks...that works excellent..you save my day. I lost two weeks trying to accomplish this and then i decided to ask here on stackoverflow..thanks again Dhruv Saxena..you save my project to go in development where i stoped...thanks...and cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here i im testing this with 4 select box...and i noticed when i select first two box value that values in select box 3 & 4 does not disable selections from 1 & 2 select box...i see this in script when i add 10 items...for first two select box it works as expected but for others 3 & 4 does not...here is code that posted above Dhruv Saxena..if someone could please see why this does not work as expected...for example this need to work as described:

Select Box #1 Test Selected
Select Box #2 Test 2 Selected & Test is disabled (update Select Box #1 Test 2 disabled)
Select Box #3 Test 3 Selected & Test & Test2 disabled (update Select Box #1 Test 2 & Test3 disabled & update Select Box #2 Test 3 disabled)

And so on..so the qoal is to when item is selected in current select box to disable this item in all other select boxes...

```js
$("select").on("change", function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).parent().siblings()
           .find("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group 1">
    <select id="1">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="4">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group 2">
    <select id="2">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="4">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group 3">
    <select id="3">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="4">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group 4">
    <select id="4">
        <option>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="4">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```