# Multiple on change on two select options

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select

I'm trying to make 2 selects, one is Request Type one is Request Number
like this:

[image]

- inside the Request Type is:CR,PR,BR,BPI,T
- inside the Request Number is:CR,PR,BR,BPI,T(T is supposed to be disabled when BPI is chosen)

here's the code:

```html
<td>Request Type</td>

<select name='cr_type' id='cr_type' >

    <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
    <option value='CR'>CR</option>
    <option value='PR'>PR</option>
    <option value='BR'>BR</option>
    <option value='T'>T</option>
    <option value='BPI'>BPI</option>

<td>Request Number</td>

<select name='cr_code' id='cr_code' >

    <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
    <option value='CR'>CR</option>
    <option value='PR'>PR</option>
    <option value='BR'>BR</option>
    <option value='T'>T</option>
```

and i want to make it so that if i choose CR,PR,BR,and T, they will auto-generate into Request Number of the respective type(CR into CR, PR into PR, BR into BR,and T into T),then disabled so it cannot be changed, and if i choose BPI, they turn into manual select CR,PR,and BR.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: See if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991965/2298301) is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var crType = document.getElementById("cr_type"),
  crCode = document.getElementById("cr_code");
  
crType.onchange = function() {

 var value = crType.value;
 
 if (value !== 'BPI') {
  crCode.value = value;
  crCode.disabled = true;
 } else {
  crCode.value = '';
  crCode.disabled = false;
 }

};
```

```html
<td>Request Type</td>
<select name='cr_type' id='cr_type'>
 <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
 <option value='CR'>CR</option>
 <option value='PR'>PR</option>
 <option value='BR'>BR</option>
 <option value='T'>T</option>
 <option value='BPI'>BPI</option>
</select>

<br>

<td>Request Number</td>
<select name='cr_code' id='cr_code' >
 <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
 <option value='CR'>CR</option>
 <option value='PR'>PR</option>
 <option value='BR'>BR</option>
 <option value='T'>T</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can get code below:
(You need to have jQuery library on your page)

```
<td>Request Type</td>
<select name='cr_type' id='cr_type'>
    <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
    <option value='CR'>CR</option>
    <option value='PR'>PR</option>
    <option value='BR'>BR</option>
    <option value='T'>T</option>
    <option value='BPI'>BPI</option>
</select>
<td>Request Number</td>
<select name='cr_code' id='cr_code'>
    <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
    <option value='CR'>CR</option>
    <option value='PR'>PR</option>
    <option value='BR'>BR</option>
    <option value='T'>T</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cr_type').on('change', function () {
            var crVal = $(this).val(),
                crCode = $('#cr_code'),
                optionT = crCode.find('option[value="T"]');

            if ("BPI" === crVal) {
                optionT.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                crCode.val('');
            } else {
                optionT.removeAttr('disabled');
                crCode.val(crVal);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer hope it solve your problem

```
<form method="post">

  <td>Request Type</td>

  <select name='cr_type' id='cr_type' onchange="submit()">
    <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
    <option value='CR'>CR</option>
    <option value='PR'>PR</option>
    <option value='BR'>BR</option>
    <option value='T'>T</option>
    <option value='BPI'>BPI</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <td>Request Number</td>

<?php if(($_POST['cr_type']=="BPI")){  ?>
  <select name='cr_code' id='cr_code' >
    <option value=''>-Pilih-</option>
    <option value='CR'>CR</option>
    <option value='PR'>PR</option>
    <option value='BR'>BR</option>
    <option value='T'>T</option>
  </select>
<?php }else if(($_POST['cr_type']!="BPI")){ ?>
  <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $_POST['cr_type'] ?>" readonly>
<?php }else if(!isset($_POST['cr_type'])){ ?>
  Silakan Pilih request Type
<?php } ?>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('cr_type').value = "<?php echo $_POST['cr_type'];?>";
</script>
```